# Redis command on a timed out key

Tags: redis

From the [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/expire/):

> A key is passively expired simply when some client tries to access it, and the key is found to be timed out.

I want to set a TTL on a Redis key (that holds a set of strings). I do this initially by doing a `SADD` (which, if the key doesn't exist, it creates one). Then some time later, I will go and try to add to this set. If at this time, the set is expired, then all good, just re-create the key in Redis and proceed as everything is normal. If the key is not expired, still all good. Just add the new item to the existing set.

My question is, what happens when I try to set add (SADD) to a key that is in a "timeout" state?  Redis doc seems to suggest that the key will be expired if client tries to access it while it is in a timed out state. Does that mean my command (SADD) errors? Or will it do what I want, which is behave as if the key was expired and re-create the key and then SADD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean my command (SADD) errors?

No, you command will succeed.

> Or will it do what I want, which is behave as if the key was expired and re-create the key and then SADD?

Yes, Redis locates the key, and finds that it should be expired. Then Redis deletes the key, creates a new set, and adds the member into the new set.